# Looking to resolve missing cost basis after transfer of funds to another brokerage

Tags: cost-basis

Back in 2021, I transferred all of my assets to a different brokerage. After the transfer completed, two of four assets have had an incomplete cost basis due to missing information for a very small lot amount.

Looking at the statement from the original brokerage, I see that fractional shares of assets were sold off prior to the transfer with no other sales having occurred throughout the holding period. These fractional share sales are presumably what's causing the incongruency, however I am not sure how to validate this because the quantity specified in the missing lot of each incomplete stock in the new brokerage does not seem to correspond to the dollar value of the proceeds of the sale.

I have unsuccessfully tried getting the dollar amount to match by taking the specified quantities in the incomplete lots and getting the dollar value against the total current market value and against the market value at the time of transfer for each stock.

Anyone have any ideas for how else to confirm this?